# Why do my Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) functions for stock simulation produce different results?

Tags: python, simulation, finance, stock, montecarlo

I have run some stock simulation using GBM. I have written two functions, one is using the for-loop and is more computationally expensive. After that, I wrote another which is vectorized and thus more efficient. However, after displaying the results, it seems that the functions display a bit different behaviour.Even though the plots look very similar the mean is different for both of them - the first function has a mean around 105 and the other around 102. I do not think that such a difference is just due to randomness (especially when run with 1,000 simulations)

```
import  numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 
np.random.seed(123)

def MC_gbm1(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n):
    start_time2 = time.time()
    dt = float(T) / n
    paths = np.zeros((n+1,M), np.float64)
    paths[0] = S0
    for t in range(1, n + 1):
        rand = np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(dt), M)
        paths[t] = paths[t-1] * np.exp((mu- 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt +
                                         sigma * rand)
    comp_time2 = round(time.time() - start_time2,4)
    print("Computation time:", comp_time2)
    return paths

def MC_gbm2(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n):
    #timesteps = np.linspace(0, T, n+1)[:,None]
    dt = T / n

    dW = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(n, M))
    dW_cumsum = np.cumsum(dW, axis=0)

    paths = S0 * np.exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt + sigma * dW_cumsum)
    result = np.concatenate((np.full((1,M), S0), paths), axis=0)
    return result

# Parameters
mu = 0.1
n = 100 # number of steps
T = 1 # time in years
M = 1000 #no of sims
S0 = 100 
sigma = 0.3

# GBM Simulation 1
St = MC_gbm1(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)

# GBM Simulation 2
St3 = MC_gbm2(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)

# Plot the results
sequence = np.linspace(0, T, n+1)
tt = np.full(shape = (M,n+1), fill_value=sequence).T

plt.plot(tt,St)
plt.title("GBM simulation 1")
plt.ylabel("Stock price")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.show()     

plt.plot(tt,St2)
plt.title("GBM simulation 2")
plt.ylabel("Stock price")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MD5i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsoTo.png)

I have tried to modify the functions in several ways but nothing really changed. Ideally, I would like to see two very means and plots (of course taking into account the slight randomness given by the stochastic nature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand the difference, note that resetting the seed between the two following operations results in the exact same matrix of noise:

```
n = 10                                                                                                                
M = 1000                                                                                                              
dt = 1 / 10                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                      
rands = np.empty((n, M))                                                                                              
# Operation 1                                                                                                         
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
for i in range(n):                                                                                                    
    rands[i] = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), M)                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# Operation 2                                                                                                         
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
dW = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(n, M))                                                                    
                                                                                                                      
print("Equal matrices?", np.allclose(rands, dW)) # True
```

So the difference must come from the order and amount of operations in each function. In fact, if you turn off the random noise in each function by doing

```
paths[t] = paths[t-1] * np.exp((mu- 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * np.zeros_like(rand))
```

and

```
paths = S0 * np.exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt + sigma * np.zeros_like(dW_cumsum))
```

both functions produce different matrices:

```
# GBM Simulation 1                                                                                                    
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
St = MC_gbm1(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)                                                                                  
                                                                                                                      
# GBM Simulation 2                                                                                                    
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
St2 = MC_gbm2(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
print("Equal matrices?", np.allclose(St, St2)) # False
```

In this case, the difference comes from how you generate the `t` iteration in method 1: you use the previous value to compute the next one. Changing the corresponding line to

```
paths[t] = S0 * np.exp((mu- 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * np.zeros_like(rand))
```

both functions will give the same result when the noise is turned off.

Finally, when you turn on the noise, the source of the difference is the extra step in method 2: the `cumsum` spoils the result. If you simply do

```
paths = S0 * np.exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt + sigma * dW)
```

in addition to the already discussed

```
paths[t] = S0 * np.exp((mu- 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * rand)
```

you will get the *same* result:

```
# GBM Simulation 1                                                                                                    
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
St = MC_gbm1(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)                                                                                  

# GBM Simulation 2                                                                                                    
np.random.seed(123)                                                                                                   
St2 = MC_gbm2(S0, mu, sigma, T, M, n)                                                                                 

print("Equal matrices?", np.allclose(St, St2)) # True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just replaced the two lines of code you suggest. Even though it is working and I get the same matrices, I think this is not correct GBM-theory-wise. After plotting the results s, I get very weird plots looking like a white noise. My understanding is that in the first function there needs to be the dependence on the t-1 because the stock path has to continually progress. In the same vein, the second function has the cumsum for the same reason. But maybe there should be cumprod instead.

Comment: The question sought to understand why the functions gave different results. This is what I provided. While I understand your concern about the theory, my advice is to mark this question as solved, and open a new question regarding how to achieve what you want using vectorized operations.